# Azure ARM template enabling Linux Diagnostic Extension with automatically generated SAS token

Tags: azure, diagnostics, azure-diagnostics, sas-token

I'm trying to deploy arm template with New VM and setting up Linux Diagnostic Extension/LAD without the creation of new Storage account but using an existing one. I found this article https://samcogan.com/generate-sas-tokens-in-arm-teamplates/ to use "listAccountSas" and I've set in "ProtectedSettings":

> "storageAccountSasToken":
>   "[listAccountSas(parameters('existingStorageName'), '2018-07-01',
>   variables('accountSasProperties')).accountSasToken]"

```
"resources": [
{vm creation bla bla},

   {
      "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions",
      "apiVersion": "[providers('Microsoft.Compute','virtualMachines/extensions').apiVersions[0]]",
      "location": "[parameters('vmLocation')]",
      "dependsOn": [ 
          "[concat('Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/', parameters('vmName'))]"     
         ],
      "name": "[concat(parameters('vmName'), '/LinuxDiagnostic')]",      
      "properties": {
          "publisher": "Microsoft.Azure.Diagnostics",
          "type": "LinuxDiagnostic",
          "autoUpgradeMinorVersion": true,
          "typeHandlerVersion": "3.0", 

          "protectedSettings": {
            "storageAccountName": "[parameters('existingStorageName')]",
            "storageAccountSasToken": "[listAccountSas(parameters('existingStorageName'), '2018-07-01', variables('accountSasProperties')).accountSasToken]",  

            "storageAccountEndPoint": "https://core.windows.net/",
            "sinksConfig": {
              "sink": [
                {
                  "name": "WADMetricJsonBlob",
                  "type": "JsonBlob"
                }
              ]
            }  

            },

          "settings": {
          "StorageAccount": "[parameters('existingStorageName')]",
          "ladCfg": {
              "diagnosticMonitorConfiguration": {
                  "eventVolume": "Medium", 
                  "metrics": {
                    "metricAggregation": [
                      {
                        "scheduledTransferPeriod": "PT1H"
                      }, 
                      {
                        "scheduledTransferPeriod": "PT1M"
                      }
                    ], 
                    "resourceId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines', parameters('vmName'))]"
                  }, 

                  "performanceCounters": {
                    "sinks": "WADMetricJsonBlob",
                    "performanceCounterConfiguration": [                                
                      {
                        "annotation": [
                          {
                            "displayName": "Memory percentage", 
                            "locale": "en-us"
                          }
                        ], 
                        "class": "memory", 
                        "counter": "percentusedmemory", 
                        "counterSpecifier": "/builtin/memory/percentusedmemory", 
                        "type": "builtin", 
                        "unit": "Percent"
                      }

                    ]
                  }, 
                  "syslogEvents": {}
                }, 
                "sampleRateInSeconds": 15
              }
            }                  
          }

      },
```

When I try to deploy the template I get an error during validation:

> "InvalidTemplate","message":"Deployment template validation failed:
>   'The template reference 'myExistingStorageAccount' is not valid: could
>   not find template resource or resource copy with this name. Please see
>   https://aka.ms/arm-template-expressions/#reference for usage
>   details.'."}

According to MS:

> The reference function and list* functions don't create an implicit
>   dependency when the resource is referred to by its resource ID. To
>   create an implicit dependency, pass the name of the resource that is
>   deployed in the same template.

However, I tried with a nested template where to "create" the SAS token and in outputs to set sasToken.Id where later on to call, in my Main template, Diagnostic Extension with sastoken.Id:

```
{
    "apiVersion": "2017-08-01",
    "name": "SasTokenNestedTemplate",
    "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
    "dependsOn": [
        "[concat('Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/', parameters('vmName'))]"
    ],
    "properties": {
        "mode" : "Incremental",
        "template": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "parameters": {},
        "variables": {},
        "resources": [
            {
                "apiVersion" : "2018-03-01",
                "type":  "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
                "name": "NestedSasTokenCreation",
                "properties": {
                    "sasToken": "[listAccountSas(parameters('existingStorageName'), '2018-07-01', variables('accountSasProperties')).accountSasToken]"
                    }
                }
                ],
                "outputs": {
                    "sasToken": {
                      "type": "string",
                      "value": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Resources/deployments', parameters('sasToken'))]"
                    }
                  }
            }
        }
    },


   {
    "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions",
    "apiVersion": "[providers('Microsoft.Compute','virtualMachines/extensions').apiVersions[0]]",
    "location": "[parameters('vmLocation')]",
    "dependsOn": [ 
        "[concat('Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/', parameters('vmName'))]"      
     ],
    "name": "[concat(parameters('vmName'), '/LinuxDiagnostic')]",      
    "properties": {
        "publisher": "Microsoft.Azure.Diagnostics",
        "type": "LinuxDiagnostic",
        "autoUpgradeMinorVersion": true,
        "typeHandlerVersion": "3.0", 

        "protectedSettings": {
          "storageAccountName": "[parameters('existingStorageName')]",
          "storageAccountSasToken": { "value": "[reference('SasTokenNestedTemplate', '2017-08-01').outputs.sasToken.value]" }, 

          "storageAccountEndPoint": "https://core.windows.net/",
          "sinksConfig": {
            "sink": [
              {
                "name": "WADMetricJsonBlob",
                "type": "JsonBlob"
              }
            ]
          }
```

But still getting the same error as above.
Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to give it resource id of the storage account, because its not the part of the template, it cant figure it out on it own.

```
listAccountSas(resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', parameters('existingStorageName')), '2018-07-01', variables('accountSasProperties')).accountSasToken
```

Comment: You are my hero! Thanks a lot mate!